# Asynchronous PHP calls to C#

Tags: c#, php, asynchronous

```
$fp = fsockopen($this->_xmlHost, 443, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp)
{
    //echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
}
else
{
    $result = $this->curlSpost($this->_xmlUrl, $sendXml ,10);
    $result = str_replace('getlicinfoold','getlicinfo', $result);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    fclose($fp);
    return $xml;
}
```

Above is some PHP code that I need to convert to C#.

My question is what is the purpose of using fsockopen and is it necessary to convert for the c# side? Can't I just send the curl via WebRequest in c# and be done with it?

Comment: What's asynchronous about fsockopen?

Answer (score 1):

Just send your request using the WebClient class.  Its abstracted a bit more than using WebRequest.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28VS.80%29.aspx